# get an array output of a Stored Procedure in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, stored-procedures, output

I have created a stored procedure to count the number of works for each technician using the ID of that technicain and the intended year as a inputs to that stored procedure, but I have stucked to . . . 
How can I get an array of output in that procedure so that ***I can use it later in my code in php*** for example.
Here is my stored procedure:

```
        DROP PROCEDURE `work_count`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `work_count`(IN `id` INT, IN `yearInput` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN 
    SET @x := 1; 
    WHILE @x<13 DO 
       SELECT COUNT(work.workType) 
       FROM work 
       WHERE year(workDate)=yearInput 
          AND work.technicianID = id 
          AND month(workDate)= @x; 
       SET @x := @x+1; 
    END WHILE; 
 END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're executing mulitple queries, you need to create a temporary table to hold your intermediate results, and then just make `SELECT * FROM thattemporarytable` one of the last things done in your procedure.

Something like this...

```
BEGIN
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `blah` ( num INT );
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `blah` ( num INT );
   SET @x := 1; 
   WHILE @x<13 DO 
      INSERT INTO blah (num)
      SELECT COUNT(work.workType) 
      FROM work 
      WHERE year(workDate)=yearInput 
            AND work.technicianID = id 
            AND month(workDate)= @x
      ; 
      SET @x := @x+1; 
   END WHILE; 
   SELECT * FROM blah;
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE blah;
END
```

or, if you can manage it as a single query, a normal select should work:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(work.workType) 
   FROM work 
   WHERE year(workDate)=yearInput 
         AND work.technicianID = id 
         AND month(workDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
   ;
END
```

Comment: The second thing is how to use that result `SELECT* FROM tbl_someTable` in a php can it be fetched like normal with `while ($row = ...fetch_assoc()){}`

Comment: If you do not drop the temporary table at the end of the procedure, it can be used on the same database connection (that is the scope of temporary tables); but that should not be necessary. Executing the stored procedure (even from php) should already provide that result set; that is the purpose of that `select *` even being in the proc.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a temporary table to store data into it then publishing it using select statement and dropping the temp table at end of the procedure

```
BEGIN


  drop TABLE if exists `myDB`.`tbl_temp`;
  CREATE TABLE `myDB`.`tbl_temp` ( `countingWork` INT(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;   
  SET @x :=1;
  WHILE @x<=12 DO
      insert into `myDB`.`tbl_temp`
      SELECT COUNT(work.workType) 
      FROM work
      WHERE year(workDate)=yearInput 
            AND work.technicianID = id 
            AND month(workDate)= @x;
      SET @x = @x + 1;
  END WHILE;
  SELECT * from `myDB`.`tbl_temp`;
  drop TABLE `myDB`.`tbl_temp`;
END
```